How to integrate FastAI classifier into sklearn VotingClassifier?
I have a bunch of tabular data and I managed to train a RandomForestClassifier, a GradientBoostingClassifier and a deep learning model (the tabular learner from fastai) with them. I noticed in the results that every model does better then the others in a particular label, different for every model. I was wondering if I could put all the models into a VotingClassifier (the one from sklearn). I have no problem with the RandomForestClassifier and the GradientBoostingClassifier but I didn’t find anything about putting the tabular learner inside the VotingClassifier. Is it possible to do that?
